# Python Numpy 2d array with non-integer index

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

Background: I'm trying to build affinity matrix to feed into sklearn spectral clustering.

In this problem, I encounter the problem where numpy array indexes are 0-based integer, and for my application I'm using some sort of application specific ID (string-based, a random example "abc123"). I would like to create a 2d numpy array indexed by all the data points I have. For instance, given two points `points = ["abc123", "xyz456"]`, I would have 2d numpy array whose row indices and column indexes are `points`. So that I could easily specify the distance between two points by something similar to `arr["abc123"]["xyz456"] = dist`

How could I achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: Why not using a dictionary?

Comment: Because I need to feed that into sklearn, which takes np 2d array, IIUC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) can do this and much much more...

```
In [41]: import pandas as pd

In [122]: a = np.random.randint(100, size=(5, 3))

In [123]: a
Out[123]:
array([[53,  7, 34],
       [54, 56, 85],
       [ 0, 11, 83],
       [63, 28, 88],
       [65, 19, 44]])

In [124]: df = pd.DataFrame(a, index=list('abcde'), columns=list('xyz'))

In [125]: df
Out[125]:
    x   y   z
a  53   7  34
b  54  56  85
c   0  11  83
d  63  28  88
e  65  19  44

In [126]: df.loc[['a','d'], ['x','y']]
Out[126]:
    x   y
a  53   7
d  63  28
```

we can always get a Numpy array from the DataFrame using `.values` accessor:

```
In [127]: df.values
Out[127]:
array([[53,  7, 34],
       [54, 56, 85],
       [ 0, 11, 83],
       [63, 28, 88],
       [65, 19, 44]])

In [128]: df.loc[['a','d'], ['x','y']].values
Out[128]:
array([[53,  7],
       [63, 28]])
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I feed pandas DataFrame into sklearn spectral clustering?

Comment: @clwen, most of `sklearn` methods accept Pandas DataFrames. And you can always get a Numpy array out of a DataFrame: `df.values` - will return you a corresponding Numpy array

Comment: Hi @MaxU thanks for your reply. In the example you gave, column indexes are still 0-based integer. I did a bit of search, it seems pandas multi-indexing is the way to go though.

Comment: @clwen, it depends on your needs. I could make another example if you would provide a small reproducible input data set and your desired data set...

Comment: Basically what I have in mind is that row index and column index are the same (set of data points). My question briefly mentions this. But I do see you modify the answer and I think that's adequate info for me. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dictionary with keys but if you still require numpy array you can play with `dtype`. From the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html):

```
>>> dt = np.dtype([('name', np.unicode_, 16), ('grades', np.float64, (2,))])
>>> x = np.array([('Sarah', (8.0, 7.0)), ('John', (6.0, 7.0))], dtype=dt)
>>> x[1]
('John', [6.0, 7.0])
>>> x[1]['grades']
array([ 6.,  7.])
```